# Multipart/form-data showing 500 error in console in live server

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please take a note that the form works well in xampp server,

This is my image upload controller:

```
function uploadPhoto()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('photo_model', 'picManager');
    $this->load->model('user_model', 'userManager');

    $result = array();

    $user = $this->userManager->get($this->session->userdata("user_id"))->result_array();
    $user = $user[0];

    $user_id = url_title($this->session->userdata('user_id'));

    if(DEMO_MODE == 1) {
        $result["status"] = 500;
    } else {
        if($user_id == null)
        {
            $result["status"] = 0;
        } else {

            $this->load->model("site_model");
            $settings = $this->site_model->get_website_settings()->result_array();
            $settings = $settings[0];

            $max_upload = $settings["upload_limit"];
            $user_photos = $this->picManager->count_user_photos($this->session->userdata("user_id"));

            if($user_photos >= $max_upload && $max_upload != 0) {
                $result["status"] = 998;
            } else {

                // Check if the directory already exists
                if (!file_exists("./uploads/photos/" . $user_id . "/")) {
                    mkdir("./uploads/photos/" . $user_id . "/");
                    mkdir("./uploads/photos/" . $user_id . "/thumbnails/");
                }

                // Copy the file to the correct directory
                if (!empty($_FILES))
                {
                    $nameFile   = rand(0,999999).time();
                    $tempFile   = $_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'];
                    $fileSize   = $_FILES['upl']['size'];
                    $fileTypes  = array('jpg','jpeg','png', 'JPG', 'JPEG', 'PNG'); // File extensions
                    $fileParts  = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name']);
                    $targetPath = "./uploads/photos/" . $user_id . "/";
                    $targetPathThumb = $targetPath . "thumbnails/";
                    $targetPathEcho = "/uploads/photos/" . $user_id . "/";
                    $targetPathEchoThumb = "/uploads/photos/" . $user_id . "/thumbnails/";
                    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $nameFile . "." . $fileParts["extension"];
                    $targetFileThumb = str_replace('//','/',$targetPathThumb) . $nameFile . "." . $fileParts["extension"];
                    $targetFileEcho = str_replace('//','/',$targetPathEcho) . $nameFile . "." . $fileParts["extension"];
                    $targetFileEchoThumb = str_replace('//','/',$targetPathEchoThumb) . $nameFile . "." . $fileParts["extension"];

                    if($fileSize <= 7000000)
                    {
                        if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
                            // Send the file
                            $file = $this->compress_image($tempFile, $targetFile, 100);

                            $thumbWidth = 800;

                            // Create the thumbnail
                            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg( $file );
                            $width = imagesx( $img );
                            $height = imagesy( $img );

                            // calculate thumbnail size
                            $new_width = $thumbWidth;
                            $new_height = floor( $height * ( $thumbWidth / $width ) );

                            // create a new temporary image
                            $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );

                            // copy and resize old image into new image
                            imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );

                            // save thumbnail into a file
                            imagejpeg( $tmp_img, $targetFileThumb );

                            if($user["gender"] == 1) {
                                $word_gender = "her";
                            } else {
                                $word_gender = "his";
                            }

                            $this->load->model('action_model', 'actionModel');
                            $this->actionModel->add($this->session->userdata('user_id'), 17, "<a href='" . base_url("user/profile/" . $this->session->userdata('user_id')) . "'>" . $this->session->userdata('user_username') . "</a> uploaded new photos on " . $word_gender . " profile.", base_url("user/profile/" . $this->session->userdata('user_id')), "<i class='fa fa-picture-o'></i>");

                            // Add picture in the DB 
                            $pic_id = $this->picManager->add($targetFileEcho, $targetFileEchoThumb, $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
                            $result["status"]   = 1; 
                            $result["photo"]    = $targetFileEcho;
                            $result["id"]       = $pic_id; 

                            // Count user photos
                            $nb_user_photos = $this->picManager->count_user_photos($this->session->userdata('user_id'));

                            // User has just one photo, set it as the profile picture
                            if($nb_user_photos == 1) {
                                $this->userManager->update_info($this->session->userdata('user_id'), array("main_photo" => $pic_id));

                                $this->session->set_userdata(
                                    array(
                                        "user_avatar"   => $targetFileEchoThumb,
                                    )
                                );
                            }

                        } else {
                            $result["status"] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }

    header('Content-type: application/json;');
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

while my form is

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="main_container clearfix">
        <div class="photo_area clearfix">
            <div class="photoblock col-md-12 clearfix">
                <div class="add_photos clearfix">
                    <form id="upload" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>photo/uploadPhoto" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="clearfix">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend><?php echo $this->lang->line("select_photos_to_upload"); ?></legend>
                        </fieldset>
                        <div id="drop">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo $this->lang->line("select_some_photos"); ?></a>
                            <input type="file" name="upl" multiple />
                        </div>

                        <ul class="wait_list">
                            <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
                        </ul>

                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
```

and my js is

```
(document).ready(function() {

$(".btn-save-photos").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var photo_array = [];

    $(".photo_line").each(function() {

        var photo = $(this).find(".photo_url").attr("data-id");
        var title = $(this).find(".title_img").val();
        var tags = $(this).find(".tags_img").val();

        // Create the info_array
        var info_array = {
            photo_id : photo,
            title : title,
        };

        // Add the info_array to the global array
        photo_array.push(info_array);
    });

    $.ajax({ 
        url: base_url + "photo/save_photos_infos",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {photo_array: photo_array},
        success: function(data) {
            window.location.href = base_url + "user/settings?action=photos_added";
        }
    });   
});
```

and

```
 $('#upload').fileupload({

    // This element will accept file drag/drop uploading
    dropZone: $('#drop'),
    limitMultiFileUploads: 5,
    sequentialUploads: true,

    // This function is called when a file is added to the queue;
    // either via the browse button, or via drag/drop:
    add: function (e, data) {

        if(data.files[0]['type'] != 'image/png' && data.files[0]['type'] != 'image/jpg' && data.files[0]['type'] != 'image/jpeg'){ alert("Whoops! You can only add photos with the .PNG or .JPG extension."); return; }

        var tpl = $('<li class="working"><input type="text" value="0" data-width="48" data-height="48"'+
            ' data-fgColor="#0788a5" data-readOnly="1" data-bgColor="#3e4043" /><p></p><span></span></li>');

        if(data.files[0].size > 7000000)
        {
            alert(photo_weight_error_str);
            return;
        }

        // Append the file name and file size
        tpl.find('p').text(data.files[0].name)
                     .append('<i>' + formatFileSize(data.files[0].size) + '</i>');

        // Add the HTML to the UL element
        data.context = tpl.appendTo(ul);

        // Initialize the knob plugin
        tpl.find('input').knob();

        // Listen for clicks on the cancel icon
        tpl.find('span').click(function(){

            if(tpl.hasClass('working')){
                jqXHR.abort();
            }

            tpl.fadeOut(function(){
                tpl.remove();
            });

        });

        var t = "";
        // Automatically upload the file once it is added to the queue
        var jqXHR = data.submit().success(function(result, textStatus, jqXHR){

            if(result.status == 1)
            {

                $(".no-photo-yet").hide();

                var nb_photo_line = $(".photo_line").length+1;

                // We create the table of images for the informations (title, tags...)
                var photo_block = "<tr class='photo_line' data-cpt='" + nb_photo_line + "'>";
                photo_block += '<td style="width:35%;"><img class="col-md-12 photo_url" data-id="' + result.id + '" src="' + base_url + result.photo + '" class="img-responsive" /></td>';
                photo_block += '<td class="infos_photo">';
                photo_block += '<div class="form-group form-title">';
                photo_block += '<label for="inputTitle">' + description_str + ' :</label>';
                photo_block += '<textarea class="form-control title_img" id="inputTitle" placeholder="' + description_placeholder_str + '"></textarea>';
                photo_block += '</div>';
                photo_block += '</td>';
                photo_block += '</tr>';

                $(".img_list").append(photo_block);

                $(".img_list").fadeIn();
                $(".buttons_send_photos").fadeIn();

            } else if(result.status == 500) {
                alert(demo_mode_str);
            } else if(result.status == 998) {
                alert(upload_limit_reached_str);
            }

        });

    },

    progress: function(e, data){

        // Calculate the completion percentage of the upload
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);

        // Update the hidden input field and trigger a change
        // so that the jQuery knob plugin knows to update the dial
        data.context.find('input').val(progress).change();

        if(progress == 100){
            data.context.removeClass('working');
        }
    },

    fail:function(e, data){
        // Something has gone wrong!
        data.context.addClass('error');
    }
```

I have checked the error console it shows 500 error however nothing shows up in php error log.

The php.ini if fine and is as follows:

```
file_uploads = On
; cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
; Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
; To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
; For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)

allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = On
asp_tags = Off
display_errors = Off
enable_dl = Off
max_execution_time = 160
max_input_time = -1
max_input_vars = 5000
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 25M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
upload_max_filesize = 200M
zlib.output_compression = On
```

It does not look like a code error but I don't think there is a php.ini defect too, Or am I missing some Multipart/form-data module or something like that if it's there?

PS: My client is using Codeigniter 3.17 and PHP 5.6 in my live server and PHP 7.2 In development and is not ready to upgrade to 7.2.

**Update:**

Here is the header the request is sending:

```
Request URL: http://website.zone/photo/uploadPhoto
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: 104.223.9.60:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: close
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 01 Apr 2018 12:05:27 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: ci_session=0bhdlk98ikpg8kt9t01f74tv8fume9di; expires=Mon, 02-Apr-2018 12:05:28 GMT; Max-Age=86400; path=/; httponly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 77761
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarySNBB3Umf4KztkRFQ
Cookie: ci_session=0bhdlk98ikpg8kt9t01f74tv8fume9di; timezone=Asia/Kolkata; cpsession=loveorfriend%3aYNtMFQrlWeAurWRT%2ce8e83a30384c80b1d190f3af375d1bda
Host: website.zone
Origin: http://website.zone
Referer: http://website.zone/photo/add
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
------WebKitFormBoundarySNBB3Umf4KztkRFQ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upl"; filename="myphoto.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
------WebKitFormBoundarySNBB3Umf4KztkRFQ--
```

**Update 2:**

As Per Alex recommendation in comments I tried to change my environment from production to development and testing and again back to production but I still do not get any error, Once again, I'd like to tell that its not showing any error anywhere but in console and It also shows blank when I click preview to know more about the issue.

Comment: If there was an php.ini error, PHP wont start. Your title says "...on live server" but you also notice that it "...works well in live server.". What is your actual result you got from the AJAX call and what is your expected result (response headers and body).

Comment: @MikeReiche Hi, I want it to upload to the server, While in live server it does not.

Comment: @MikeReiche Ah! A typo sorry.

Comment: Ok. I dont know if we unterstand each other correctly. But the server script you provide would send a JSON result on upload. But the script DOES NOTHING if the constant DEMO_MODE=1 and will output somelink like {"status":500"}. Are you sure, that this constant is either not defined or not "1"?

Comment: @MikeReiche Yes, Its 0.

Comment: When the server responds with HTTP 500 Internal Server Error, than your script is invalid. You should view into the php error log defined in ini_get('php.error_log') or the error logs of Apache or Nginx web servers.

Comment: @MikeReiche Thats what the issue is, Its not showing any error.

Comment: Did you set the base url in config.php

Comment: Go in index.php in the switch statement copy the code in the development section into the production section. Upload to server. Then retry and your errors should be visible.

Comment: Unrelated: you should use || not &amp;&amp; when you check if images are jpg or png and alert in dz. As it is now it will only alert if the file type is all (not possible).

Comment: @Alex Thanks but my development in xampp's index.php is the same as servers, Can you tell which line?

Comment: Doesnt matter, just follow the instructions. It's at the top of index.php... and upload to server.

Comment: @Alex It does not work,It does not show any errror and not even in Console, However, I updated the post with header response if it can be detected via it.

Comment: strange... usually works. keep it at development, and run phpinfo() somewhere and look for `error_reporting` and see what the val is. basically, it is really really hard for us to debug without knowing the error and the headers don't help much. it is possible that is a db error so turn on db debug in database.php

Comment: @Alex , Yes, It does not work, however, in phpinfo It shows php_error off even when php.ini in the server says on, I'd also like to point out that I have around 380+ clients using the same script and had no issues, However, This client has the issue, The issue is, In my knowledge  I don't think that enctype/formdata requires any modules/